# Graph a system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to graph this system of equations:

[image]

Also will be helpful if anyone can explain how to write it in Mathematica 12.  I mean, how to use the { and to make columns and rows as it is shown

This does not seams to work:

[image]

Comment: I'm still confused. What do you want to ask?

Comment: There is a [Mathematics.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) site where this question might be more appropriate. Your input is fairly far off from something that would work, though, so you'd probably be pointed to [Mathematica's Plot documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html).

Comment: what is your question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then you may asking how to plot this kind of function. First of all, It's basically not a system of equation it is simply [piecewise function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise). If you want to plot it in Mathematica $12$ then here is the code:
`Plot[Piecewise[{{-1, x <= -1}, {x, -1 < x < 0}, {x^2,x >= 0}}], {x, -3, 3}]` 
And one more thing don't forget to use $??\text{Piecewise}$ in Mathematica for more information. Let me know Am I rightly understand your question or not.